# Firebase Analytics For Web Not Flowing To BigQuery

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

BigQuery is not receiving any data from Firebase Analytics for web. It appears Firebase dashboard is receiving the events and data correctly, but the dashboard is buggy. For example, sometimes when I view my events tab it ask me to setup an app (which I already have).

[image]

Then I refresh and I see my events fine. This goes back and forth all day.

[image]

Here is my setup:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.2.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.2.0/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
<script src="/static/init-firebase.js"></script>
```

Then I log the events:

```
const defaultAnalytics = window.firebase && window.firebase.analytics();
if (defaultAnalytics){
   defaultAnalytics.logEvent('viewedNote', { noteId, accountUID, videoId, contactId, fromText, socialshare, forBDay});
}
```

Sometimes my events show, sometimes they don't like I document above. But right now I can see my events from yesterday (even though some refreshes ask me to setup an app again).

My real concern is I don't have any data in BigQuery for analytics. Note: I fired events over 12 hours ago and still nothing.

[image]

And here are my integrations:

[image]

[image]

How do we make data flow to Bigquery?

Comment: Please contact Firebase support for troubleshooting problems with the Firebase console.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple fix. You need more than 100 events for data to flow to BigQuery. Firebase support answered this question for me.

Comment: Interesting. My events definitely are showing up, while `SELECT count(*) FROM \`project_name.analytics_ID.events_*\` ` shows 27.

Comment: It's weird. Mine showed up sometimes under 50 events, but not every time. I also never get the intraday table which support said was because I didn't have 100 events.

Comment: Yeah, it could be that this just applies to intraday tables, which I also haven't used yet. Don't forget to accept your own answer once the system allows it.

Comment: @Will any solution??

Comment: I ended up using a different approach. As Fran mentioned, you need to have more than 100 events per day for this to work.